# Finding Apex classes via the Partner API that contain test cases

Tags: soap-api

How can I determine via the APIs that an Apex class contains test cases?

I can query ApexClass, but there is no immediate field indicating the class contains tests.

Assuming the body field content is available (not from a managed package), do I need to manually search the contents of the Body field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know there's no field to indicate the presence of test methods.

I think you're right, you'll have to scan the code by searching the body field manually (since long text fields aren't available for filtering in SOQL) for the `testmethod` keyword and `@IsTest` annotation.

You may want to cater for commented varieties too, though this might be overcomplicating the situation.

---

SOSL Example to find (potential) classes containing tests.

```
FIND {@IsTest or testMethod} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING ApexClass(Id, Name)
```

Comment: I'd also need to look for instances of @IsTest. I can definitely pull the body for any ApexClass. Unfortunately I can't filter on it in SOQL. INVALID_FIELD - "field 'Body' can not be filtered in query call"

Comment: Yeah, you're right about `@IsTest`. You can never filter on the long text fields on SObjects, which is presumably what's used for the body. Guess you'd have to grab all the classes and search on the body yourself using `indexOf` or similar.

Comment: Also note that managed package classes can contain test methods that are executable via the web interface but would not be detected by this method.

Comment: If you need to be precise you'd also need to ensure that the `testMethod` and `@isTest` instances aren't with a comment, text string or SOQL query (as unlikely as that is) as well.